# MongoDb profiling doesn't show any output

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I enabled MongoDb (`v3.4.0`) profiling level 2:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

The result is:

```
{ "was" : 2.0, "slowms" : 100.0, "ok" : 1.0 }
```

I validated it using `db.getProfilingStatus()`:

```
{ "was" : 2.0, "slowms" : 100.0 }
```

Then I ran some queries and called:

```
db.system.profile.find({
"command.pipeline": { $exists: true }
}, {
"command.pipeline":1
}).sort({$natural:-1}).pretty();
```

The result is not an error but it is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Reducing the `slowms` value using `db.setProfilingLevel(2, {slowms: 10})` didn't change the profiling output.

**Update**:

This query returns some results after issuing several queries against the database:

```
db.system.profile.find({"planSummary":{$eq:"COLLSCAN"},
"op" : {$eq:"query"}}).sort({millis:-1})
```

Comment: Are you actually actively running any other queries on "that database" before checking for entries? Note the command must be run on the same database namespace where your queries are going and that you make sure you don't have unit test code that "drops" the database. I once sat around for 40 minutes until I realized I was dropping a database I had just set profiling on and then wondering what happened. At profiling level 2 the `slowms` has no effect as that level just logs everything anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, I’m running the queries against the database by using the application. Also, I've updating the question.

Comment: The only queries I see here are against `system.profile` itself. Where are the queries you are running against the other collections which should be logging here? Or did you think this just allowed you to see you whole query history? You enable profiling, run queries against the database, then look in the profiler for data on those queries.

Comment: That's what I did.